# Rotate TIFF Image VB.NET Console Application

Tags: .net, vb.net, console-application

I have a console application that performs some OCR on a large TIFF image (about 6MB image) Before i perform the OCR i need to rotate the image.

I imported the system.drawing namespace and my rotation code is as follows:

```
 Dim bmp As System.Drawing.Bitmap
 bmp = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(fileName)
 bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)
 bmp.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it gives me Parameter is not valid error. The strange thing is, i am using the same exact test image every time, just with different file names. I did check that the filename being passed is valid....

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes it gives me Parameter is not valid error

Part of your problem could be that, the Save method will throw an exception if you save the image to the same file it was created from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

You could rename the file or delete the original first.

Comment: Its not the save method that is throwing the exception, its the New System.Drawing.Bitmap. Im wondering if it has something to do with a console application and GDI calls?